# Can I use HAProxy's new 'capture' feature to save the remote address in a TCP frontend, and use it as the `X-Forwarded-For` header in an HTTP backend?

Tags: ssl, haproxy, packet-capture

Using HAProxy 1.6 and a [clever hack](https://jve.linuxwall.info/blog/index.php?post/2015/10/04/SHA1/SHA256-certificate-switching-with-HAProxy), I now have an HAProxy tcp mode frontend, that detects if the browser is capable of SNI, and based on that, routes to a strongly ciphered SSL termination backend, or a weaker one. This ensures A+ grading on SSL labs, while still allowing all browsers except IE6 to use SSL.

Here is my config. It has some template variables in it that should be self-explanatory, but aren't in areas relevant to my question:

```
frontend https_incoming
 bind 0.0.0.0:443
 mode tcp
 option tcplog
 tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
 tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }
 use_backend https_strong if { req.ssl_sni -m end .transloadit.com }
 default_backend https_weak

backend https_strong
 mode tcp
 option tcplog
 server https_strong 127.0.0.1:1665

frontend https_strong
 bind 127.0.0.1:1665 ssl crt ${DM_ROOT_DIR}/envs/ssl/haproxy-dh2048.pem no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets ciphers ${strongCiphers}
 mode http
 option httplog
 option httpclose
 option forwardfor if-none except 127.0.0.1
 http-response add-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000
 reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
 reqadd FRONT_END_HTTPS:\ on
 use_backend http_incoming

backend https_weak
 mode tcp
 option tcplog
 server https_weak 127.0.0.1:1667

frontend https_weak
 bind 127.0.0.1:1667 ssl crt ${DM_ROOT_DIR}/envs/ssl/haproxy.pem no-sslv3 ciphers ${weakCiphers}
 mode http
 option httplog
 option httpclose
 option forwardfor if-none except 127.0.0.1
 http-response add-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000
 reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
 reqadd FRONT_END_HTTPS:\ on
 use_backend http_incoming
```

Problem: the `https_incoming` frontend knows the Client IP, but since it is in `mode tcp`, it cannot save this information in a `mode http` `X-Forwarded-For` header. `option forwardfor` is not valid in TCP mode.

From [another question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/302282/how-can-i-use-haproxy-with-ssl-and-get-x-forwarded-for-headers-and-tell-php-that)
I already found that I could use:

- LVS
- PROXY protocol

So that the `X-Forwarded-For` header isn't even needed anymore as from what I understand, in the case of LVS: packets are spoofed so the source becomes the  Client IP, and in the case of PROXY: packets are encapsulated to carry the Client IP.

These both seem like they could work. LVS however seems quite a heart-surgery for us that could have side-effects, and PROXY has the downside that proxies/application upstream/downstream, might not be fully compatible yet.

I was really hoping for something more lightweight, and that's when I found the new ["Capture" feature of HAProxy 1.6](http://blog.haproxy.com/2015/10/14/whats-new-in-haproxy-1-6/) as it mentions:

> you can declare capture slots, store data in it and use it at any time during a session.

it goes on to show the following example:

```
defaults 
 mode http

frontend f_myapp
 bind :9001
 declare capture request len 32 # id=0 to store Host header
 declare capture request len 64 # id=1 to store User-Agent header
 http-request capture req.hdr(Host) id 0
 http-request capture req.hdr(User-Agent) id 1
 default_backend b_myapp

backend b_myapp
 http-response set-header Your-Host %[capture.req.hdr(0)]
 http-response set-header Your-User-Agent %[capture.req.hdr(1)]
 server s1 10.0.0.3:4444 check
```

It appears to me, information is stored in a frontend, and then later used in a backend, so perhaps I can take the Client IP in TCP mode, save it, and use that later down the line, maybe like so:

```
http-response set-header X-Forwarded-For %[capture.req.hdr(0)]
```

I've looked at the [capture docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4.2-capture%20request%20header) and there it seems capture is more oriented at http mode headers, but then I have also seen a [mailing list conversation](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/19341) successfully demonstrating the use of a `tcp-request capture`.

I've tried several things, among which:

```
tcp-request capture req.hdr(RemoteAddr) id 0
# or
tcp-request content capture req.hdr(RemoteHost) id 0
```

But as you can see, I haven't got a clue what the syntax should be and under which key this information would be available, nor can I find it in [the (I think) relevant documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4.2-tcp-request%20connection).

Questions: Would it be possible to capture the Client IP in TCP mode, and later down the line, write this information into the `X-Forwarded-For` header in HTTP mode? If so, what would be the syntax for this?

Comment: Can't help you right now, but wanted to say: Great question with great explanations! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, this does not seem possible, as the traffic 'leaves' HAProxy here:

```
       TCP                             HTTP
frontend->backend (->leaving->) frontend->backend
```

So the context is lost and the capture cannot be preserved. Instead, as "PiBa-NL" suggested on IRC at #haproxy on Freenode yesterday:

```
[5:29pm] PiBa-NL: kvz, use proxy-protocol between back and front
[5:54pm] kvz: PiBa-NL: Thanks, does this mean my app also needs to understand 
         the proxy protocol, or will it be 'stripped' once it reaches the 
         backend. I don't think my node.js server could handle it without  
         significant changes to its stack
[6:07pm] kvz: Or let me rephrase: could I enable the proxy protocol on the first 
         frontend, then 'unwrap' it in the second frontend, taking the client ip 
         and putting it into the http header - so that my app would not have to 
         be proxy protocol compatible, and it would just be means to carry the 
         client ip from first frontend to the second?
[6:49pm] PiBa-NL: kvz, the last part you can still use the x-forwarded-for header
[6:50pm] PiBa-NL: but between haproxy backend and frontend you would use the 
         proxyprotocol to make the second frontent 'know' the original client ip
[6:50pm] PiBa-NL: server https_strong 127.0.0.1:1665 send-proxy
[6:50pm] PiBa-NL: bind 127.0.0.1:1665 ssl crt .... accept-proxy
[6:52pm] PiBa-NL: the second frontend can then still use the  
         'option forwardfor', and it should insert the wanted header
[6:53pm] PiBa-NL: so basically 'yes'
```

This means the PROXY protocol is only used to glue the two frontends together, encapsulating the Cient IP, but the second frontend unwraps it and saves it in the `X-Forwarded-For` header via `option forwardfor`, so that its backend can send a PROXY-protocol-less request to my app server, meaning I do not have to worry about compatibility issues up/downstream.

Comment: kvz, I've inserted some `\n` into the IRC log to make it readable without vertical scrolling. Hope that's fine for you..

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy should already be adding the X-Forwarded-For header.  You may want to add protocol and/or port if either of these is non-standard.

I usually test this sort of behavior with a page that echos the request headers.  That makes it easy to see what headers are available, and what their contents are.

It is not unusual for X-Forward-For to contain a list of addresses.  This signals that the request has passed through multiple proxies, or someone is spoofing the header.  The right most address will be the one that was added by the last proxy (ha-proxy) that handled the request.

Some web servers can be configured to log an IP address from a header rather than the connection.  This would be useful for your access logs, and a case where you would want to generate a header based on the incoming connections IP address.

It is possible to achieve an A+ rating while supporting all the listed browsers except IE 6  Without using two different stacks.

- For Java 6 disable at least DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA and AES128-SHA.  It is possibly all ciphers without forward secrecy.
- For WinXP/IE8 and Java6 enable DES-CBC3-SHA and/or EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA.  These should be the least preferred ciphers as they don't support forward secrecy.

WinXP/IE8 and Java 6 do not support Forward Secrecy with a secure protocol, so the test does not penalize your for its failure.  All other browsers will use forward secrecy if you enforce server ordering.  (Win Phones fail if you don't.)

A rating of A+ requires setting Strict-Transport-Security with a time period of at least 180 days.

Comment: Thanks! But if this is true, it defies my understanding. I'm thinking, since in the tcpfrontend->tcpbackend -> httpfrontend->httpbackend  the connection 'leaves' HAProxy, the second frontend will receive a connections from 127.0.01, and all context is lost, no? 

This actually makes me wonder if capture can be used at all, also. I guess not. I received this reply on IRC though (cannot inline due to comment char restrictions: https://gist.github.com/kvz/4388c4e6971a78c5e1674f1905e3c0f6)

Indicating to me that I can use the proxy protocol without affecting any entity up/downstream.

Comment: @kvz I hadn't noticed that you are trying to fake out SSL Labs to falsify your score. Yes, in your case I would expect 127.0.0.1 to be the X-Forward-For source.

Comment: @kvz Other than Java6, IE8 on XP, and IE 6, you shouldn't need to fake out your security.  Your method may fake the results of the test, but don't give you A+ security.  See: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=apollo.systemajik.com for A+ without faking the test  Your question got me to review my settings earlier than I planned.   Thanks for the prod.

Comment: Dropping HTTPS support for those platforms is not an option for us yet unfortunately, as we're a service provider and can't make assumptions about the audiences our customers want to target with their sites/apps. Some in fact have to deal with more corporate environments where BC-breaking Java6 would not fly well). I wouldn't say this fakes security though, I'd say this provides the best SSL termination that each client platform can support (yet excluding sslv3)

Comment: @jvz Anyone wanting to break your SSL will find the less secure protocols and use them.  Your rating should be based on them.  Modern clients will use the more advanced and secure settings, which older clients don't support. The test is intended to measure your weakest access, which you are gaming the test to increase your score.  In my opinion, selling your service as having an A+ rating is not honest.

Comment: @kvz I would offer clients A+ without the hack and a less secure termination which supports Java 6. It appears Java 6 build 111 supports 2048 bit keys. The bouncy castle libraries provide an alternative fix.

Comment: When you say "Anyone wanting to break your SSL will find the less secure protocols and use them" what good will that do other than being able to decrypting their own traffic? They cannot force strong clients to stop announcing SNI and degrade their cipher suites. Also, since sslv3 is disabled, there is no risk of leaking my certificates or similar (?) Yet weaker clients can still use SSL vs no protection at all, at least making their attack surface smaller.

Comment: @kvz  See my update.  End discussion.